# Snowflake Python connector only returns two query results

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using `snowflake.connector` to run four queries one after another. All queries should return some results, but only the first two return results. If I comment out the first two, then the next two queries would successfully return results. It seems like there is a soft limit of two somewhere. Any idea what is wrong?

```
self.cnxn = snowflake.connector.connect(
            user=self.username,
            password=self.password,
            account=self.account,
            warehouse=self.warehouse)
self.cursor = self.cnxn.cursor()

self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM db.schema.table1")
rows = self.cursor.fetchall()

self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM db.schema.table2")
rows = self.cursor.fetchall()

self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM db.schema.table3")
rows = self.cursor.fetchall()  # returns empty resultset 

self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM db.schema.table4")
rows = self.cursor.fetchall()  # returns empty resultset
```

Note that I don't get any error messages.

Answer (score 3):

I can not reproduce. What versions are you using?

This worked well for me:

```py
cnxn = snowflake.connector.connect(
            user=user,
            password=password,
            account=account,
            warehouse='s')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM "KNOEMA_ECONOMY_DATA_ATLAS"."ECONOMY"."EPUUI2019Apr" LIMIT 3""")
print(cursor.fetchall())
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM "KNOEMA_ECONOMY_DATA_ATLAS"."ECONOMY"."BEANIPA" LIMIT 3""")
print(cursor.fetchall())
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM "KNOEMA_ECONOMY_DATA_ATLAS"."ECONOMY"."BLSLA" LIMIT 3""")
print(cursor.fetchall())
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM "KNOEMA_ECONOMY_DATA_ATLAS"."ECONOMY"."DP_LIVE" LIMIT 3""")
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

[My config](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/preconfigured-amazon-sagemaker-instance-with-snowflake-connector/) is the Snowflake provided Sagemaker image.

Now, if the queries are independent of each other and each takes time to run, your code might benefit from running them asynchronously:

```py
import time
start = time.time()

cnxn = snowflake.connector.connect(
            user=user,
            password=password,
            account=account,
            warehouse='s')

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute_async(
    """SELECT * FROM "KNOEMA_ECONOMY_DATA_ATLAS"."ECONOMY"."EPUUI2019Apr" LIMIT 3""")
query_id_1 = cursor.sfqid
cursor.execute_async(
    """SELECT * FROM "KNOEMA_ECONOMY_DATA_ATLAS"."ECONOMY"."BEANIPA" LIMIT 3""")
query_id_2 = cursor.sfqid
cursor.execute_async(
    """SELECT * FROM "KNOEMA_ECONOMY_DATA_ATLAS"."ECONOMY"."BLSLA" LIMIT 3""")
query_id_3 = cursor.sfqid
cursor.execute_async(
    """SELECT * FROM "KNOEMA_ECONOMY_DATA_ATLAS"."ECONOMY"."DP_LIVE" LIMIT 3""")
query_id_4 = cursor.sfqid

for id in [query_id_1, query_id_2, query_id_3, query_id_4]:
    while cnxn.is_still_running(cnxn.get_query_status(id)):
      time.sleep(1)
    cursor.get_results_from_sfqid(id)
    print(cursor.fetchall())
print(time.time() - start)
```

Comment: Snowflake Connector for Python Version: 2.3.10, Python Version: 3.6.8, Platform: Windows-10

Comment: Can you upgrade to v2.4.1(March 04,2021)? I don't see any relevant changes since v2.3.10(February 01,2021), but it won't hurt to update.

https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/blob/master/DESCRIPTION.rst